# Replace any index in a text frame with output of a method

Tags: c#, list, methods, replace, linq-to-sql

I design a frame for message with a some index in it for each person in list. like the one bellow:

```
  Dear {0} 
  Hi, 
  the total amount of Draft is {1}.
  amount of prm is {2}
  yesterday amount is {3}
```

I wrote a method witch return all different type of amount and insert the out put of method in a list . I want to replace each item of text frame with the correct amount .

for example the output like the list bellow :

| sale | reject amount | damage amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1230 | 56555 | 79646354 |

my method like bellow :

```
     public List<outputList1> listAmount()
    {

        var amounts = (from p in db.FactTotalAmount
                       
                       group p by p.FromDate  into g
                         select new outputList1
                         {

                             YesterdaySalesPrm = g.Sum(x => 
                               x.YesterdaySalesPrm),
                             YesterdayDraftAmount = g.Sum(x => 
                              x.YesterdayDraftAmount),
                             PrmSales = g.Sum(x => x.PrmSales),
                             DraftAmount = g.Sum(x => x.DraftAmount)
                         }).ToList();

        return amounts;
    }
```

would you please help me what should I do

Comment: Can you post the method you have written so far?

Comment: The code you've posted seems to gather data, but you aren't showing any attempt at doing text replacement. Have you heard of `string.Format()`? What have you tried to create the output string?

Comment: I want this output : Hi, 
  the total amount of Draft is 123654213
  amount of prm is 654231
  yesterday amount is 9774654

Comment: I've heard about it but no success yet ! I use for each for every body in list and try to add new column to list that is complete

Comment: I wrote this line but when I put coma and add more than two parameter it raise error     
    var a = string.Format(s.SmsFramText , s.Sex , s.LName  );

Comment: And what was the error?

Comment: indentifier expected :(

Comment: var a = string.Format(s.SmsFramText, s.Sex, s.LName, "2021-07-20" , amt.[0] , amt.[1] , amt.[2] , amt.[3]);

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with `string.Format` itself. It's because you wrote `amt.[0]`. You can't put indexer syntax (the square brackets) directly after a member accessor (the period).

Comment: thank you dear aunr2171

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to teach you to fish.

There are two main ways to build a string using a template - formatting and interpolation.

Option one: use [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___):

```
string output = string.Format("Today is {0}. Weather is {1} at {2}°.", "Monday", "rain", 75.2);
// result is "Today is Monday. Weather is rain at 75.2°."
```

Option two: use C# 6 [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
string dayOfWeek = "Monday";
string weather = "rain";
decimal temp = 75.2;

// Notice the "$" at the start of the string literal
string output = $"Today is {dayOfWeek}. Weather is {weather} at {temp}°.";
```

So, you have a model - the data you've collected - and a format string. Combine those together with one of these options to produce the final output string.